# partial application in clojure

Tags: clojure, currying

How do you do partial application in Clojure?

I have tried:

```
(dorun (map println ["1" "2" "3" "4"]))
```

which works.

```
(async/send! channel "hello")
```

works too.  But if I try to apply partial application

```
(dorun (map (async/send! channel) ["1" "2" "3" "4"]))
```

or

```
(dorun (map #(async/send! channel) ["1" "2" "3" "4"]))
```

or

```
(apply (partial map (async/send! channel) ["1" "2" "3" "4"]))
```

It says

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: immutant.web.async/send!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clojure currying is different than in languages like ML, F# or Haskell.

There are 2 ways to do partial application in Clojure:

1. Making closure, where you can specify the exact order of arguments:

   `(fn [coll] (map str coll))` of `#(map str %)`
2. Using partial, which will substitute arguments in order they provided:

   `(partial map str)`

When you call function with less arguments than it requires you'll get `ArityException` (unless it's a multi-arity function, that can accept different number of arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this seems to work:

```
    (dorun (map (partial async/send! channel) ["1" "2" "3" "4"]))
```

A bit confused why this didn't work

```
    (dorun (map #(async/send! channel) ["1" "2" "3" "4"]))
```

Comment: partial and `#()` produce two separate types of functions. With `#()` you need to explicitly specify where the parameters are inserted, e.g. `#(async/send! channel %)`